# Delete data frame column within function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
df<- iris

library(svDialogs)
columnFunction <- function (x) {
  column.D <- dlgList(names(x), multiple = T, title = "Spalten auswaehlen")$res
  if (!length((column.D))) {
    cat("No column selected\n")
  } else {
    cat("The following columns are choosen:\n")
    print(column.D)
    for (z in column.D) { 
      x[[z]] <- NULL #with this part I wanted to delete the above selected columns
    }
  }
}

columnFunction(df)
```

So how is it possible to address data.frame columns "dynamically" so:  `x[[z]] <- NULL` should translate to:

```
df$Species <- NULL
df[["Species"]] <- NULL
df[,"Species"] <- NULL
```

and that for every selected column in every data.frame chosen for the function.
Well does anyone know how to archive something like that? I tried several things like with the `paste` command or `sprintf, deparse` but i didnt get it working. I also tied to address the data.frame as a global variable by using    `<<-`   but didn`t help, too. (Well its the first time i even heard about that). It looks like i miss the right method transferring x and z to the variable assignment.

Comment: Note, use `message` or `warning` instead of `cat` to provide user information. This becomes relevant when working in executable scripts, and it’s also formatted differently inside the interactive R console (depending on some packages). Never use `cat` to provide user information, use it only to actually print *data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a function `columnFunction` that removes columns from a passed data frame `df`, all you need to do is pass the data frame to the function, return the modified version of `df`, and replace `df` with the result:

```
library(svDialogs)
columnFunction <- function (x) {
  column.D <- dlgList(names(x), multiple = T, title = "Spalten auswaehlen")$res
  if (!length((column.D))) {
    cat("No column selected\n")
  } else {
    cat("The following columns are choosen:\n")
    print(column.D)
    x <- x[,!names(x) %in% column.D]
  }
  return(x)
}

df <- columnFunction(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! One last question: Is it in any way possible to include the last step ("df <- columnFunction(df)") into the function?

Comment: @Deset yeah, you can. For instance, you could change the last line to `df <<- x` instead of `return(x)`. However that's pretty poor coding practice so I wouldn't suggest it.