# Delete data.frame columns and loop through data.frame assignment function

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I found the following piece of  code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120875/delete-data-frame-column-within-function/32122160#32122160) at stackoverflow:

```
library(svDialogs)
    columnFunction <- function (x) {
      column.D <- dlgList(names(x), multiple = T, title = "Spalten auswaehlen")$res
      if (!length((column.D))) {
        cat("No column selected\n")
      } else {
        cat("The following columns are choosen:\n")
        print(column.D)
        x <- x[,!names(x) %in% column.D]
      }
      return(x)
    }

    df <- columnFunction(df)
```

So i wanted to use it for my own proposes, but it did not work out as planned.
What i try to archive is to use it in a `for loop` or with `lapply` to use it with multiple data.frames. Amongst others I tried:

```
d.frame1 <- iris
d.frame2 <- cars

l.frames <- c("d.frame1","d.frame2")

for (b in l.frames){
  columnFunction(b)
}
```

but it yields the following error message:

```
Error in dlgList(names(x), multiple = T, title = "Spalten auswaehlen")$res : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Well, what i need additionally is that I can loop though that function so that i can iterate through different data.frames.
Last but not least I would need something like:

```
for (xyz in l.frames){

xyz <- columnFunction(xyz)
}
```

to automate the saving step.

Does anyone have any idea how i could loop though that function or how i could change the function so that it performs all those steps and is loopable. 
I`m quite new to R so perhaps Im missing something obvious.

Comment: Look at `l.frames`. Then change its creation to `l.frames <- list(d.frame1, d.frame2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the first problem. Now Im able to loop through the function. The last step Im missing is to save the changed dataframes under the same name. Dynamically because the input dataframes can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` was designed for this task:

```
l.frames <- list(d.frame1, d.frame2)
l.frames <- lapply(l.frames, columnFunction)
```

If you insist on using a `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(l.frames)) l.frames[[i]] <- columnFunction(l.frames[[i]])
```

Comment: The new data.frames are saved in l.frames. Is it possible to extract those with their original names (d.frame1, d.frame2)?

If the data.frames have names by creating them for example like this:
**l.frames <- list(d.frame1 = d.frame1 , d.frame2 = d.frame2)**
and i use **list2env(l.frames, environment())** i could archive that.
But now the question would be how to assign those name automatically while creating the list(l.frames).

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use `mget`. But there should be no reason for using  `list2env`. Keep them in a list.

Comment: I need them as own data.frames with those names, because I want to further process them independently and in the end export and names them like their data.frame names.

Comment: O.k. I figured it out thanks to your hint to use `mget`. Now everything works fine! Thank you!